# Nodejs nested child process not running | child_process | nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, sh, child-process

Im using 'child_process' package to execute a bash script from nodejs, I have two scripts that need to be executed, one immediately and another that runs after a period of time (30 seconds).

For some reason, the nested child does not run, or runs with an error that I can not see, perhaps its outputting to its parent, not the root process, i'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

What i'm exactly trying to do:
Run a shell script from node js, some services need some time to initialize, so another shell script has to run after some time, usually 30 seconds max.

Code:

```
import shell from 'child_process';

const runFirstScript =  (name) => {
    return shell.execFile('./first_script.sh', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        //Assuming no errors occur (tested it works fine)
            shell.execFile('./second_script.sh', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            // Code never reaches here, it just pauses.
            // If program stopped and ran manually, it works perfectly.
       });
    });
}
```

I assume running a nested child is done wrong here, or its actually outputting some information but I can't see it because its outputting to its parent, either way, the script does not work.

I have tried callbacks, separating functions, its all the same, at last I figure it could be something related to child processes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using [execFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options) instead?